# gRPC server streaming for persistent connections

Tags: websocket, grpc

I currently use WebSockets for pushing server events to a mobile client. The WebSocket is basically open while a user is using an app, which can be many hours.

As we are rewriting the parts of the app that receives server side events, I'm considering whether WebSockets would still be the best choice. One option is to use gRPC. Are there any issues if I do the following query on like:

```
service ClientConnection {
  rpc ServerEvents (ConnectionOpen) returns (stream ServerEvent) {}
}
```

Now when the client starts, I would do a single `ServerEvents` RPC and then for the rest of the session keep waiting for `ServerEvents`. Is there any problems doing this if I wait for messages for a long time? This would logically be equivalent to waiting for data over a WebSocket connection.

How does gRPC handle if the connection fails? How does the server detect that a connection was closed and the stream is now dead? Other issues when keeping a connection open for a long time and possible be idle with no `ServerEvents` for tens of minutes? Any reason why I should not use gRPC instead of WebSockets in this case?

All clients are native apps and we will never need browser clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work.

> Is there any problems doing this if I wait for messages for a long time?

Long-lived connections can make load balancing harder. Use max_connection_age and max_connection_age_grace on the server to limit connection lifespan.

> How does gRPC handle if the connection fails?

The call will fail. In your case the app should retry.

> How does the server detect that a connection was closed and the stream is now dead?

The signal may come from TCP level but you can also enable gRPC keep-alive on the server (and if necessary on the client) to detect this faster. Note that client and server keep-alive configs must agree. I.e., if client is getting GOAWAY with the code ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM and "too_many_pings" as a reason, then the client is sending more pings (or more frequently) than the server is willing to accept.

> Other issues when keeping a connection open for a long time and possible be idle with no ServerEvents for tens of minutes?

gRPC will not move the channel to IDLE state because the server-streaming RPC will be in-flight. However, depending on your TCP config the TCP connection may go idle (gRPC keep-alive can prevent that).